connect RFID - RC522 directly to a PC using USB to TTL converter
I want to connect RFID - RC522 (Link: https://robu.in/product/rc522-rfid-card-reader-module-13-56mhz/) directly to a PC (Ubuntu 20.04) using CP2102(6-pin) USB 2.0 to TTL UART serial converter(Link: https://robu.in/product/cp-2102-6-pin/) OR PL2303 PL2303HX USB To TTL(Serial) Converter Module – 5 Pin (Link: https://robu.in/product/pl2303-pl2303hx-usb-ttl-module-5-pin/). Will I be able to do that ?

Yes, probably. Although, where is the relevance to Raspberry Pi?

No relevance to raspberry PI, I was not able to find specific group to post. So, I posted in this stackexchange.

I have edited the question. Now it links directly to the product. Can you help me.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

From your link, this image shows the Rx and Tx pins that you need to connect to the TTL UART. There is also an SPI and I2C interface. There's even a linked guide to use with an Arduino.

Thank you all for your replies. To convert from SPI to UART- It needs some cutting the module. Link & Link
